# saveAll is too slow for only one table

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

I have two tables in `MSSQL`. Essentially both are the same. But for one of these when I try to persist with `saveAll()` it takes a lot of time.

My entities are:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "INSTRUMENTOS_PIP")
@IdClass(value = InstrumentosPIPPk.class)
public class InstrumentosPIP{}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "INSTRUMENTOS_VALMER")
@IdClass(value = InstrumentosValmerPk.class)
public class InstrumentosValmer{}
```

My properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
```

This is the way that I persist. Where ***valmers*** and ***pips*** are lists with about 25,000 rows

```
vValmer.saveAll(valmers);
            valmers.clear();
            valmers = null;
            System.gc();

vPIP.saveAll(pips);
            pips.clear();
            pips = null;
            System.gc();
```

**valmers** is very fast but **pips** not. valmers spends 5 min, pips 2 hours. Doesn't matter the processing order.

I'm using `JPARepository`.

Comment: How capable your MSSQL server is to accept these many parallel requests?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried profiling your code? Also, are there any differences at all between the two tables that you could identify (e.g. different indexes)?

In general, JPA is not the ideal choice for batch operations, as it introduces significant performance overhead. You'd be better off using plain JDBC. You might also find Spring Batch handy, especially if there's another step needed to map the data onto the entities (e.g. from a file).

As a side note, you seem to be under the impression that `valmers.clear(); valmers = null; System.gc();` releases the memory occupied, but bear in mind that, if the code itself is wrapped in a transaction, then the entities remain in the persistence context. Memory-wise, it could actually prove more effective to divide the input into smaller batches and do a `JpaRepository.flush()` followed by `EntityManager.clear()` after saving each batch.